# I want to auto-populate rich text area field using selenium webdriver java

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am getting "element not interactable" using sendKeys() have tried using explicit wait so it is giving stale element error. I am able to auto-click using js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver); but not able to auto-populate the field using js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'test';", driver);

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix.
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = '"+claDesc+"'", desc);

where claDesc is variable which contains value you want to input
desc is WebElement variable which contains rich text area